# UIAlertController Keeps Re-Appearing After Closing It

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alert, uialertcontroller

I have written code for an alert to appear when the input in one of my UITextFields is less than 1050. It successfully appears when the inputs satisfies that, but after I press "OK" it instantly re-appears.

Below is the code in the `viewDidLoad` function:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter an exit width value greater than 1050", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let okay = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: valueCalc)
    alert.addAction(okay)
}
```

Then I have in my `valueCalc` function (which is called when a button is tapped):

```
@IBAction func valueCalc(sender: AnyObject){
    if(Int(mmText.text!)! < 1050){ //mmText is an UITextField
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your line of code

```
let okay = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: valueCalc)
```

Your handler name *valueCalc* is called when you press *OK*.

Again the value is calculated which when come out be less then the specified characters shows back you the alert.

Instead of that, replace this line in your code -

```
let okay = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: handlerMethod)
```

and add this method to your code

```
func handlerMethod() {

   //handle your action here after ok is pressed for e.g if you wanna just dismiss the alert then write

   dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the `handler` argument for your `UIAlertAction` set to `valueCalc`. Therefore, whenever the user taps "OK", the method `valueCalc` gets run again, and since the value is (presumably) still the same, the alert is presented right back again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter an exit width value greater than 1050", preferredStyle:      UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let okay = UIAlertAction(
        title: "OK",
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive) { (action) in }

    }

    @IBAction func valueCalc(sender: AnyObject){
    if(Int(mmText.text!)! < 1050){ //mmText is an UITextField
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```